# trying to limit products that a customer can buy with a voucher code , not working

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-enterprise, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart, magento-1.7

I've been trying to create a voucher code . 
i want to limit the products discount to 3 per person (so that the 100 % discount would be valid only on 3 products ) but for some reason it makes the whole SKU on the voucher code list discounted , it should be just maximum 3 products not all of them .

please view https://i.stack.imgur.com/yetQA.png

Answer (score 2):

The *Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To* field is quantity per-product. So if you have that field set to 3, and someone puts in a single product with a quantity of 5, the discount will only be applied 3 times. However, if you put in 5 products with a quantity of 5 each, it will be applied 3 times to each product.

See `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator`

```
/**
 * Return discount item qty
 *
 * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item
 * @param Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule $rule
 * @return int
 */
protected function _getItemQty($item, $rule)
{
    $qty = $item->getTotalQty();
    return $rule->getDiscountQty() ? min($qty, $rule->getDiscountQty()) : $qty;
}
```

Even adding an *Action* condition like this, would not work, as it would then not apply the rule at all if the customer adds more than 3.

> Quantity in cart **equals or less than** **3**

I'm not aware of a built-in way to do what you're looking to do.

Comment: so what do you suggest is there no way of doing it ?

Comment: I don't know of a way, but I can't say for sure that there isn't a little trick for it. What I can confirm for you is that Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To isn't supposed to do what you're trying to do.